# What frames are supported by the Dynamixel XL-320 OLLO?

Tags: rcservo, walking-robot, dynamixel

I was recently looking into purchasing either a Dynamixel AX-12A or XL-320. The XL seems to use OLLO frames, which only seem to be available in a toy-like set.

I was wondering if there are any other frames available or if I should just get an AX-12?

Comment: Did you ever a decision? I am wondering the same thing.